# convert data laravel use dompdf

Tags: php, laravel, dompdf

```
$pasien = pasien::all();
$pdf = pdf::loadView('laporan/viewpasien',['show'=>$pasien]);
return $pdf->download('pasien.pdf');
```

I am trying to convert data to pdf using dompdf, but the loading page is taking too long, can someone help me ?

Comment: how much record do you have from $pasien = pasien::all();

Comment: not much, only 3 record